# Do Hermite polynomials satisfy $\int(H_n(x))^2 e^{-x^2} dx= 2n \int (H_{n-1}(x))^2 e^{-x^2} dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

I'm trying to prove that the norm of the Hermite polynomials (physicist's version) equals $ 2^n n! $. I stumbled upon [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176409/417300) and I don't understand parts of the proof. First of all, it seems implied by the author that:

$$ \frac{d^n}{dx^n}H_n(x) = 2^n n!$$

But I've failed to prove it myself, using the definition (physicists' convention) and by recursion.

Alternatively, I tried to use the recursion formula:

$$ H_n'(x) = 2x H_n(x) - H_{n+1}(x)$$

And calculate the norm similarly to how the proof for the general $n \ne m$ goes:

$$ \int |H_n(x)|^2 e^{-x^2}dx = \int H_{n-1}(x) H_n'(x)e^{-x^2}dx = \int H_{n-1}(x)(2 x H_n(x) - H_{n+1}(x))e^{-x^2}dx = \int H_{n-1}(x)2 x H_n(x)e^{-x^2}dx$$

Were in the last equality, I used the fact that $H_{n+1}(x)$ and $H_n(x)$ are orthogonal.

I don't know how to prove that

$$ \int H_{n-1}(x)2 x H_n(x)e^{-x^2}dx = 2n \int |H_{n-1}(x)|^2 e^{-x^2}dx$$

I read [a comment to that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176403/a-question-of-the-norm-calculation-of-hermite-function#comment579182_176409) which I don't understand, and that can prove the last missing piece:

$$ H_n'(x) = 2n H_{n-1}(x) $$

Why is this true? Isn't it contradictory to the known recursion formula?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials There are two different common ways to normalize them.  So decide whether to use the probabilist's way or the physicist's way.  It seems the one with $2^n n!$ is the physicist's way.

Comment: I edited the question to mention that I'm using the physicist's version of the polynomials, thanks.

Comment: (The comment said 2n, not n, I edited the question to reflect this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are happy to use the following definition of the Physicist's Hermite polynomials:
$$
H_{n+1} = 2x H_n - H_n' , \quad H_0 \equiv 1 \tag{$D$}$$
The induction hypothesis we use is
$$P(n): \forall n\ge 1,\quad  H'_n=2nH_{n-1}\tag{$I$}.$$
Since $H_1(x) = 2x$, the base case is trivial: $H_1'=2\times 1\times H_0$. Inductively
\begin{align} H_{n+1}'
&\overset{(D)}=(2x H_n - H_n')' \\
&= 2H_n + 2xH_n' - H_{n}’’ 
\\
&\overset{(I)}= 2H_n+2x(2nH_{n-1}) -2n H'_{n-1}
\\
&= 2H_n + 2n(2xH_{n-1} - H’_{n-1})
\\
&\overset{(D)}= 2H_n + 2n H_n
\\
&= 2(n+1) H_{n}
\end{align}
which is what we wanted. One easily computes the norm from this and the calculation in the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176409/417300) that shows $\int |H_n|^2  e^{-x^2}dx = \int H_{n-1} H_n' e^{-x^2}dx$.

Also, its not contradictory because the defining recursive formula is made up of different terms. It would be bad if we instead proved $H_{n+1} = ax H_n +bH_n'$ for some constants $a\neq2$ and $b\neq-1$, but this is not the case.